# Is there an underlying task/service that I can restart when Discord, Chrome, Edge and VSCode all become unresponsive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio-code, chromium, discord

Windows 10 Pro, after a week or two of uptime I often run into an issue where several applications become unresponsive simultaneously. Best I can tell from my research, these applications (Discord, VSCode, Chrome and Edge) all use the Chromium rendering engine, and I would suspect that has something to do with why they all fail at once. Other applications like Firefox continue to operate without issue when this occurs. If my assumption is correct, then is there anything I can do to restart the task/service/other that these programs operate on? Obviously a system restart fixes the problem right away, but I'd rather not have to close down everything I'm working on every time this comes up. Or is there something else happening here that I have overlooked?

Potentially relevant specs:

- i5-11600K @3.9GHz
- 32GB Physical Memory
- 128 GB Virtual Memory
- 96GB pagefile.sys

Comment: Since I (and likely lots of other users) use services like this and do not have this issue, it is a problem with your OS. Consider doing a Repair Install to make the system work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such problems before.
They are usually caused by a lack of some resource, by a memory leak or
similar. Such problems can be extremely hard to diagnose, and if the
problem is with Windows itself then they are impossible to fix.

Rebooting is always the best solution in order to initialize all the
resources. However, as you say, not something you would like to do in the
middle of your work.

A method I have used before is to schedule a reboot at night every day
or every week, as suitable.
This controlled reboot solves this particular problem and the computer
will function without problem during the day.